# .htaccess file doesn't work correctly when I change my url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url from:

```
 www.domain.com/includes/edit.php?products=cloth
```

to:

```
 www.domain.com/products/cloth
```

I'm using this code right now but it's not working:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ edit.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess file? and please explain what is not working

Comment: my htaccess file is in my root folder

Comment: its poducts brother it was my mistake but it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /includes/edit.php?products=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /edit.php?products=$1 [NC,L] it not worked also